# jQuery.AJAX / JSON output becomes mixed up

Tags: jquery, html

I'm still fairly new to jQuery, but I was trying to get some output from an API using AJAX to my website as a test, and so far it's done pretty well... but my issue is that it rearranges the order in a strange way. I'll post my code below and then explain it

HTML

```
<p id="beatmap-name1"></p>
<p id="beatmap-id1">1179268</p>
<p id="beatmap-name2"></p>
<p id="beatmap-id2">582801</p>
<p id="beatmap-name3"></p>
<p id="beatmap-id3">1179268</p>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{  
var $mapID = $('#beatmap-id' + i).text();

$.ajax({

  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=...&b=' + $mapID,
  success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, map){
      counter++;
      $('#beatmap-name' + counter).text(map.title);
        })
      }

    })
  }
})
```

I guarantee I'm doing this in a very inefficient manner, however this is just a matter of "will it work" or "will it not work".

In summary, the jQuery code will start by taking the map IDs within beatmap-id1, 2, and 3. One by one. When it takes one of them it will insert it into a variable, $mapID, which will then insert it into the API URL. This link brings up a specific JSON based on the ID entered. Now, after it gets the mapID entered and the JSON code in place, it is supposed to take a specific part of that JSON code and output it in the loop. However, for some reason it outputs in a strange way and never in a very consistent way. Such as the map name (which I'm calling to output) will be in random, inconsistent, orders. How would I go about fixing a problem like this? (I have heard JSON rearranges the order in which it outputs, but I don't understand if it applies to this problem)

Comment: Remove your client id from that.

Comment: @AHBagheri If you mean $mapID then that won't work. The whole purpose of that mapID is to call a specific JSON based on the map ID itself. Without the $mapID the entire program wouldn't work (it's a parameter in the api documentation found here: https://github.com/ppy/osu-api/wiki)

Comment: I think @AHBagheri 's point is just for you to remove it from the post, not from the code. To stay anonymous.

Comment: @Sylvain is right. I mean remove from the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation to your 'random inconsistent order' is due to the random order in which you receive your responses. You are firing multiple ajax requests in your code and you are assuming that they will respond in the same order you requested them, and that's the problem, ie: request for id 1 might receive its response after the request for id 2 and in your code your counter will be assigned in the order that your responses arrive not in the order that your requests are triggered.

In order to fix your code just remove the counter variable and add an anonymous function to solve the index problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
 {  
   var $mapID = $('#beatmap-id' + i).text();

   var fn  = function(index){
       $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=a51bbccbf7f74898e481e8176caf7189ceae36cd&b=' + $mapID,
          success: function(data){
                      $.each(data, function(var1, map){
                         $('#beatmap-name' + index).text(map.title);
                      })
                   }
        });
   };

  fn(i);
 }
});
```

Comment: How would this work? Because the counter was used to make sure I could target '#beatmap-name1, 2, and 3'. The $mapID just defeats that purpose entirely, and the output doesn't work.

(I tried your code and nothing worked for me as well)

Comment: You are right, I was confused and thought mapID was the index. I've edited my answer, should work now

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually worked for me (I kept refreshing and they always showed up at the same specific place in the output).

Answer (score 1):

The whole point about AJAX is to be asynchronous. So even if your request are in send in a specific order, it's not guaranteed that the callback function will be called in the same order.

For example if the second beatmap is longueur to load, it may be possible that the callback associated to its request will be executed after the callback for the third beatmap.

You should find a way to replace the counter with a variable having the value of `i`.

EDIT: I isolated the ajax call in a function `ajaxRequest` and it seems to be working:

EDIT 2: seems that @artemisian already gave this solution a while ago.

Here is the script:

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        ajaxRequest(i);
    }

    function ajaxRequest(j) {
        var $mapID = $('#beatmap-id' + j).text();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=a51bbccbf7f74898e481e8176caf7189ceae36cd&b=' + $mapID,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, map) {
                    $('#beatmap-name' + j).text(map.title);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: '#beatmap-name' + i never worked for me sadly.  It wouldn't output anything in that case, and I'm not sure why that is. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @reyder Then you can try to create a new variable. `var j = i;` just before `$.ajax` and then use `j` instead.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work either. It instead only affects the third beatmap-name html ID, and loops through the three names in that place.